# setserial: Cannot get serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, serial-port

```
$ setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 -G
Cannot get serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What does this error mean? `stty` works fine:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
eof = ^A; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the driver does not support the IOCTL that `setserial` is using:

```
setserial gets the information via an ioctl() call. In case the driver 
for your device does not support TIOCGSERIAL, the "invalid argument" is 
returned.
```

([Debian bug report)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=311813https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=311813)

I think `stty` should be able to perform any configuration you need for a USB-Serial device.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man setserial`, or search on `manpages.ubuntu.com`. It says, in part:

```
For the most part, superuser privilege is required to set the configuration parameters of a serial port. A few serial port parameters can be set by normal users, however, and these will be noted as exceptions in this manual page.
```

Or, you could `sudo setserial ...`.

Comment: It makes no difference, I get the same error with sudo.